# How to form Insert query dynamically in this case

Tags: java

I have a input string seperated with @ symbol as shown

```
Popcorn@Bucket
```

I have a table as shown

```
mysql> desc document;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| document_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| T1              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T2              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T3              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T4              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T5              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T6              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T7              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T8              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T9              | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| T10             | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_brand_id | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_id       | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Depending on the input i am trying to form an Insert query as shown

```
 String reqstr = "Popcorn@Bucket"

String valuess[] = reqstr.split("@");

if (valuess.length == 1) {

sql = "Insert into document (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,vendor_brand_id,vendor_id) values ('"+valuess[0]+"',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"+vendor_brand_id+","+vendor_id+") ";

}
else if (valuess.length == 2) {

sql = "Insert into document (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,vendor_brand_id,vendor_id) values ('"+valuess[0]+"','"+valuess[1]+"',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"+vendor_brand_id+","+vendor_id+") ";

}

// Upto length 10
```

My question is that how can i form this dynamically ??

Comment: Can you elaborate . do you need to form the values part dynamically ?

Comment: Yes i need to form the query dynamically .

Comment: Btw you don't need to supply NULL since it is default value for attributes. sql = "INSERT INTO DOCUMENT (T1, vendor_brand_id, vendor_id) values ('"+valuess[0]+"',"+vendor_brand_id+","+vendor_id+") " would suffice. The same for the sql in else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How try like this using `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Insert into document (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,vendor_brand_id,vendor_id) values (");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i < valuess.length) {
            sb.append("'" + valuess[i] + "',");
        } else {
            sb.append("NULL,");
        }
    }
    sb.append(vendor_brand_id+","+vendor_id+")");

    //now sb.toString() is ready for required sql
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use PreparedStatement to build your query.
Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).
After building query, you can set values in the query according to the inputs received or you can set null.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can solve the dynamic aspect of your problem using StringBuilder, I would very strongly discourage this approach as it ignores the wealth of technologies/frameworks that have been developed to avoid doing this sort of thing, both for the frontend and backend.

The first thing I can point out is that even though you can pass values delimited by character, it may not necessarily be a good idea. For example, if order is important, then when someone passes (t1, t3, t6), the above approach will fail. The delimited string does not specify the order of your variables. So in order to make the delimited values correctly, you need another delimiter, and therefore add more complexity to what really should be a simple problem to address.... even if order isn't an issue, it's going to be very hard for someone else to understand what's going on using this approach; or even you, if you have to go back and look at this code after some time :)

I assume you're using Java so have a look at the following:

http://www.edu4java.com/en/servlet/servlet3.html

It should give you an idea of how to rework your problem with servlets and forms. If that's too vague or confusing then there's always Google :)

Secondly, if you get the above part correct, then you can use PreparedStatment in Java as has been suggested by others as well, without having to make anything dynamic. If your read and understand how Java works with databases, you will see there is little benefit to the dynamic SQL approach you're attempting to make. See this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Good luck and don't stop exploring